# How to show html element, on selecting specific option in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How to show the other html when selecting specific option in angularjs. I want to only show the **From Date** and **To Date** text field, when we select **Other** option, but hide these when we choose other options. I tried 
`ng-show="date_option=='Other'` nothing happened.

**DEMO** http://plnkr.co/edit/Xy49iha3bsCQui6uOaTV?p=preview
**Html**

```
  <div ng-controller="ceilometerCtrl">
    <div id="ceilometer-stats">
         <form>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Period:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select ng-model="date_option" ng-options="value.label for value in date_options">

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div >
                  <label >From:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" id="date_from" name="date_from" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label>To:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" id="date_to" name="date_to"/>
                  </div>
               </div>
        </form>
    </div>

  </div>
```

"

**Angular**

```
var app=angular.module('hz',[]);
 app.controller('ceilometerCtrl', function($scope, $http){


   $scope.date_options=[
      {
           "value" : 1,
           "label" : "Last day"
      },
      {
           "value" : 7,
           "label" : "Last week"
      },
      {
           "value" : 23,
           "label" : "Month to date"
      },
      {
           "value" : 30,
           "label" : "Last 30 days"
      },
      {
           "value" : 356,
           "label" : "Last year"
      },
      {
           "value" : "Other",
           "label" : "Other"
      }
   ];

   $scope.date_option = $scope.date_options[1];
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your js file, it looks like you would need to use `ng-show="date_option.value=='Other'"`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1m30pGNTGRaAMDbzZZQF?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Either change your ng-option to

```
ng-options="value.label as value.label for value in date_options"
```

And

```
$scope.date_option = $scope.date_options[1].label;
```

or  in ng-show use

```
ng-show="date_option.value=='Other'"
```